# PHP and SQLite V2 extension for Fedora 14

Tags: fedora, php, sqlite

How can I add support for the PHP SQLite V2 extension on Fedora 14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's available from Remi's repository:

```
php-sqlite-5.3.4-3.fc14.remi.i686.rpm - Extension for the SQLite V2 Embeddable SQL Database Engine
php-sqlite-5.3.5-1.fc14.remi.i686.rpm - Extension for the SQLite V2 Embeddable SQL Database Engine
php-sqlite-5.3.4-3.fc14.remi.x86_64.rpm - Extension for the SQLite V2 Embeddable SQL Database Engine
php-sqlite-5.3.5-1.fc14.remi.x86_64.rpm - Extension for the SQLite V2 Embeddable SQL Database Engine
```

Start here and read about YUM automatic configuration:

http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en

You get PHP with SQLite in two simple steps:

1. Add remi repository:

   ```
   rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/remi-release-14.rpm
   ```
2. Install php-sql:

   ```
   yum --enablerepo=remi install php-sqlite
   ```